# Is it possible to hack other brands of cameras in a manner similar to Canon cameras?

Tags: canon, firmware-hacks

Some Canon cameras can be hacked with a tool called the Canon Hack Development Kit (http://chdk.wikia.com), which does interesting things like add manual controls and allow scripting. Do similar tools exist for other brands of cameras? HP cameras, in particular?

Comment: Does CHDK work on Canon DSLRs or just P&S? I thought it was the latter.

Comment: Seems to just be the point-and-shoots; however, on a DSLR, you already have good manual controls, so it's not as useful.

Comment: An example would be: on my Nikon D90, button remapping is possible, but extremely limited. Hacking could increase this flexibility.

Comment: Don't forget that a few (four, I think) Canon DSLRs also have [Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki), which is in much the same spirit as CHDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chdk project is the only one I've heard of.

Answer (score 5):

There is an ongoing project to analyse and de-encrypt the firmware of Pentax DSLRs:-
[Pentax Hack](http://www.pentax-hack.info/)

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing project to analyse and decrypt the firmware of a range of Nikon cameras: [Official Nikon Hacks (d7000, D3100, D5100, V1, J1) and Nikon Tool development topic](http://www.personal-view.com/talks/discussion/1494/official-nikon-hacks-d7000-d3100-d5100-v1-j1-and-nikon-tool-development-topic/)