# Is there a firmware hack which enables AVCHD recording in video mode on Pentax K-5?

Tags: video, pentax, firmware-hacks

The Pentax K-5 supports only recording video in the MPEG format. Does a firmware update or hack exist that would allow recording in AVCHD?

Are there software hacks for the Pentax DSLRs at all?

Related: [Can a Pentax K-5 record more than 4 GB of video with an SDXC card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19745/can-a-pentax-k-5-record-more-than-4-gb-of-video-with-an-sdxc-card)

Comment: Also related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/555/is-it-possible-to-hack-other-brands-of-cameras-in-a-manner-similar-to-canon-came

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to the basic question: no, there's no hack to do this on the K-5 that I'm aware of (and I've been a Pentax shooter pre-digital).

As to the second, sort of, question: yes, there is some software hacking. The Pentax line does have a debug mode and people are accessing it, details can be found on the [Pentax Hack](http://www.pentax-hack.info/) site, though I don't think they've managed to kick the K-5 into this mode.